# Sequence of random variables that converges in distribution but whose variances does not converge to limit's variance

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I am self-studying the Lehmann's amazing book "Elements of Large Sample Theory". There is a problem that I cannot figure out:

3.7 (page 122): Give an example in which $k_n(Y_n-c)$ tends in law to random variable $Y$ with cdf, but where $Var[k_n(Y_n-c)]$ does not tend to $\nu^2=Var(Y)$.

I thought maybe a good strategy would be an example where $Y_n$ has infinite variance for any finite $n$ but asymptotically it has finite variance. But (1) I cannot think of such a sequence and (2) I'm not even sure this is the right approach.

Comment: It is not clear to me what $k_n$ means, but perhaps consider $\{Z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as a sequence of random variables that converge to 0 (in probability and/or with prob 1) but has $Var(Z_n)\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @Michael I believe $k_n$ is intended to be any sequence of constants that depends only on n. Interesting idea. I think I see your strategy.

Comment: So then for simplicity you can perhaps use $c=0$ and $k_n=1$ for all $n$.  It turns out that a small number of canonical examples can be reworked/reused to demonstrate lots of different convergence phenomena.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k_n = 1, c=0$,

Let $Y_n = \begin{cases}-n, &\text{ with probability} \frac1{2n} 
\\ 0 &\text{ with probability} 1-\frac1n\\
n, &\text{ with probability} \frac1{2n}\end{cases}$

then we have

$$Pr(Y_n \le m) = \begin{cases} 0 &, \text{if } m < -n \\ 
\frac1{2n} &,  \text{if }  -n \le m < 0 \\
1-\frac1{2n} &,  \text{if } 0 \le m < n  \\  
1&,  \text{if } m \ge  n\end{cases}$$
but 
$$Var(Y_n)=E(Y_n^2)=n^2\left( \frac1n \right)=n \to \infty$$